# Disable or Enable buttons based on some conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

In my app I have multiple divs which look like (The divs are created dynamically):

```
<div class="form-group clearfix">
    <div class="form-group first-name">
        <input type="text" id="firstName0" class="signup-input firstName required" name="first[0]" placeholder="">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group last-name">
        <input type="text" id="lastName0" class="signup-input lastName" name="last[0]" placeholder="optional">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group email">
        <input type="text" data-index="0" id="inputMail0" class="signup-input mail" name="email[0]" placeholder="e.g. example@url.com" aria-invalid="true">
        <span class="common-sprite sign-up-cross first"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The names are dynamically generated according to the index (For example the are email[1], email[2].....).

I have a button which should be disabled in case the field of the first name is `not empty` and the field of the email `is empty` and  the span hasn't a class of `disNone`.

How should I disable the button according to above condition?

Comment: possible this should from Stackoverflow, please read the T&C .. then ask question, this is not a question and answer forum, in Stackoverflow you can post question if any bug in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this condition works out for you.

Store the jQuery objects in variables and use that variables instead, which is a much better way to do it.

```
$(function(){

    var firstName = $('#firstName0').val();     
    var inputMail = $('#inputMail0').val();     
    var checkClass = $('span').hasClass('disNone');

    if( firstName!=='' && inputMail==='' && !checkClass ) {
        $('button').attr('disabled','disabled'); //in the fiddle you would see an alert, you just have to replace that code with this one
    }

});
```

**EDIT:**  If your `DIVS` are being generated dynamically  you can use the `each()` jquery function to loop through them.

```
$(function(){

$('#mainDiv').children('div').each(function(index,element){
var nameDiv = $(element).find(":nth-child(1)");
var firstName = $(nameDiv).find('input').val();   
var emailDiv =   $(element).find(":nth-child(3)");
var inputMail = $(emailDiv).find('input').val();     
var spanElem = $(emailDiv).find("span");
var checkClass = $(spanElem).hasClass('disNone');
   if(firstName!=='' && inputMail==='' && !checkClass){
     $('button').attr('disabled','disabled');
//in the fiddle you would see a console.log('hi'), you just have to replace that code with this one for whatever button you want to disable
    }
});
});
```

Checkout the **[FIDDLE LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/9966spst/2/)**

In the fiddle I have left out one `SPAN` tag **with** class `disNone` and other `SPAN` tag **without** class `disNone`. So only once the condition executes

Comment: How does the `empty` function work? Also the OP is looking that it does *not* have the span class of `disNone`

Comment: Yes, that method/function empties all the children of the given selector from what I can see?!

Comment: dentity Unkn0wn-The divs are created dynamically so your example is not good for this case

Comment: @SaritSara : Checkout the fiddle, now I have edited the code for even dynamically generated divs :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to disable the button if all of the following conditions are met:-

1. First name field is NOT empty - `$('#firstName0').val() != ''`
2. Email field IS empty - `$('#inputMail0').val() == ''`
3. Span does NOT have class of disNone - `!$('span').hasClass('disNone')`

So I would check that condition this way by wrapping it in a listener on the `keyup` event upon the form:

```
$('.form-group').on('keyup', function () {
    console.log('keyup');
    if ($('#firstName0').val() !== '' && $('#inputMail0').val() === '' && !$('.email span').hasClass('disNone')) {
        //Now do whatever with your button.
        $('.mybutton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        $('.mybutton').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ajj87Lg3/